# Get max length of multi-dimension tuple

Tags: python, tuples, variable-length

My tuple looks something like this(for a particular set of generated value)

```
tTrains = [ (3, ), (1, 3), (6, 8), (4, 6, 8, 9), (2, 4) ]
```

Now, what I need to find is the length of longest tuple inside this tuple/list. I can always use a for loop, iterate over all the sub-tuples and do it. But I want to ask if there's a predefined function for the same.

### Current Usage

This is what I am going to use as of now

```
max = 0
for i in range( len(tTrains) ):
  if iMax < len( i ):
    iMax = len( i )
```

Comment: The extra `,` in the tuples are actually important. A number in parenthesis is just a number, if you add the `,` it becomes a 1-item tuple. (I know it's not relevant for you anymore. Just in case somebody else needs it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
tup=[ (3, ), (1, 3), (6, 8), (4, 6, 8, 9), (2, 4) ]
max(map(len,tup))
```

result:

```
4
```

Comment: thanks! ps today I looked for the first time at functional programming, this solution was inspired by it

Comment: @JoelCornett no problem, I rejected the edit with the "custom" reason

Comment: Link to the map function if you're not familiar with it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't use `max` as a variable name, since this will shadow the built-in of the same name.  This built-in `max()` can be used to compute the maximum of an iterable.

You currently have a list of tuples, but you want the maximum of the list of their lengths.  To get this list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[len(t) for t in tuples]
```

(Note that I renamed your list `tuple` to `tuples`, since `tuple` would shadow the built-in type of the same name.)

Now you can apply `max()` to this list, or even better, to a generator expression constructed in a similar way.

Comment: This was merely for question purpose. My actual variable names are like: `tScreens` for a tuple of screen and so one. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution:

```
>>> tup=[ (3, ), (1, 3), (6, 8), (4, 6, 8, 9), (2, 4) ]
>>> len(max(tup, key=len))
4
```

which translates to 'give me the length of the largest element of `tup`, with "largest" defined by the length of the element'.